# SELECT where max date in subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, left-join

I've installed the TestDB from MySQL[(Test DB)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/) and I wanted to do some basic querys. One of them is: Give me every employee with their salary back. The salaries table contains a list of every salary the employee ever had with a from and to date. I only want the newes salary, so the one with the highest "from_date". I've managed to `Join` the 2 tables together and I've managed to give me back the highest salary for eache employee with their employee number. But I cant get them together. I've found nothing online. Maby I just dont know what to search.

Anyway, this is what I came up with:

Select highest salary for each emp_no:

```
select emp_no, max(from_date) from salaries group by emp_no
```

Select highest salary for each employee an join it with the other data (This one does not work):

```
select * from employees e
LEFT JOIN salaries s
ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
where s.from_date=(select max(from_date) from salaries group by emp_no);
```

This is the EER:

[image: EER]

Comment: What do you want here, the max salary or the most recent salary?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want the most recent salary. The one with the highest `from_date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the most recent salary for each employee then join the `salaries` table to a subquery:

```
SELECT e.*, s1.*
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN salaries s1
    ON e.emp_no = s1.emp_no
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS max_from_date
    FROM salaries
    GROUP BY emp_no
) s2
    ON s1.emp_no    = s2.emp_no AND
       s1.from_date = s2.max_from_date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I didnt know that you can join something on a subquerry.

Comment: It would be odd for an employee not to have a salary, but no harm done

Comment: @Strawberry Did you ever see the movie Office Space?  Anyway, for a Stack Overflow question I would cover my bases at all times :-)